Segmentation Fault (Core Dumped) When Running makemigrations with PostgreSQL in Django
I’m trying to connect my PostgreSQL-17 database to a Django project running in a Conda environment on Ubuntu-24. However, when I run python manage.py makemigrations, I keep encountering the following error:
[1]    73059 segmentation fault (core dumped)  python manage.py makemigrations

I don't know where the issue lies. Here's the relevant section of my settings.py file for the database connection:
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        # 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',  
        'NAME': os.getenv("DB_NAME", "default_db_name"),  
        'USER': os.getenv("DB_USER", "default_user"),
        'PASSWORD': os.getenv("DB_PASSWORD", "default_password"),
        'HOST': os.getenv("DB_HOST", "localhost"),  # Service name in Docker Compose
        'PORT': os.getenv("DB_PORT", "5432"),  # Default PostgreSQL port
        'CONN_MAX_AGE': int(os.getenv("CONN_MAX_AGE", '600')),
    }
}


Here's the relevant section of my .env file:
DB_ENGINE = django.db.backends.postgresql
DB_NAME = test_db          
DB_USER = test_admin          
DB_PASSWORD = test_123  
DB_HOST = localhost                     
DB_PORT = 5432
DATABASE_URL = 'postgres://test_admin:test_123@db:5432/test_db'
CONN_MAX_AGE = 600

I've also tried:

Uninstalling and reinstalling PostgreSQL completely.
Switching between 'django.db.backends.postgresql' and 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2'.
Manually entering the database credentials directly in the code (instead of using environment variables), but the error persisted.
All necessary postgresql python dependencies are properly installed in the Conda python environment.


I managed to debug the issue using the following command:
gdb --args python manage.py migrate
Inside gdb, I ran the program to trace the error:
(gdb) run
The root cause turned out to be related to conda dependencies. I resolved the problem by updating all packages with this command:
conda update --all
